# adding days to a date

Tags: java, date, gregorian-calendar

I have a program that needs to start on 1/1/09 and when I start a new day, my program will show the next day.
This is what I have so far:

```
GregorianCalendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar(2009, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy"); 
public void setStart()
{
    startDate.setLenient(false);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(startDate.getTime()));
}

public void today()
{
    newDay = startDate.add(5, 1);
    System.out.println(newDay);
//I want to add a day to the start day and when I start another new day, I want to add another day to that.
}
```

I am getting the error found void but expected int, in 'newDay = startDate.add(5, 1);'
What should I do?

Comment: Three questions in a couple of hours about dates. Maybe its time to look at the API first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object has an [`add`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) method which allows one to add or subtract values of a specified field.

For example,

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(2009, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

The constants for specifying the field can be found in the "Field Summary" of the [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Just for future reference, [The Java API Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) contains a lot of helpful information about how to use the classes which are part of the Java API.

---

**Update:**

> I am getting the error found void but
>   expected int, in 'newDay =
>   startDate.add(5, 1);' What should I
>   do?

The `add` method does not return anything, therefore, trying to assign the result of calling `Calendar.add` is not valid.

The compiler error indicates that one is trying to assign a `void` to a variable with the type of `int`. This is not valid, as one cannot assign "nothing" to an `int` variable.

Just a guess, but perhaps this may be what is trying to be achieved:

```
// Get a calendar which is set to a specified date.
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2009, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);

// Get the current date representation of the calendar.
Date startDate = calendar.getTime();

// Increment the calendar's date by 1 day.
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

// Get the current date representation of the calendar.
Date endDate = calendar.getTime();

System.out.println(startDate);
System.out.println(endDate);
```

Output:

```
Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2009
Fri Jan 02 00:00:00 PST 2009
```

What needs to be considered is what `Calendar` actually is.

A `Calendar` is not a representation of a date. It is a representation of a calendar, and where it is currently pointing at. In order to get a representation of where the calendar is pointing at at the moment, one should obtain a [`Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) from the `Calendar` using the [`getTime`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) method.

Comment: I was about to type the link to API!

Answer (score 1):

If you can swing it requirement wise, move all your date/time needs to JODA, which is a much better library, with the added bonus that almost everything is immutable, meaning multithreading comes in for free.