# getting and setting dates with Java

Tags: java, date

First off thank you for taking the time to scroll through this.

I am basically a greenhorn when it comes to Java but I am working on a program that asks the user some basic info then sets a start date and then schedules service dates at bi weekly intervals between March and October from their start date.

For the start date variable, I simply set it up as:

```
STARTDATE = getDate();
```

to give the current date when the user signs up.

I have been sifting through my searches for days but I cannot figure out how to increment the service dates by 14 days to save my life.

I tried using `SERVICEDATE = STARTDATE + (0, 14, 0);` 
but I cant make sense of whats really happening here.  Any ideas?

Comment: "...sifting through my searches..."  what does that mean?

Comment: What is the **type** of `STARTDATE`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the common-lang library. It has a DateUtils class which can be used for this. 
Use it like this:

```
SERVICEDATE = DateUtils.addDays(STARTDATE, 14);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work.  Now how can I limit it so it wont accept dates between nov and feb?

Comment: `Date yourdate = new Date();
  Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
  calendar.setTime(yourdate);
  int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  if(month >= Calendar.FEBRUARY && month <= Calendar.NOVEMBER){
   
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at this: [Java getDate date-x days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650240/java-getdate-date-x-days)

They are subtracting days but I think it can be turned into adding days too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Joda Library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

```
Date STARTDATE = getDate();
DateTime stDate = new DateTime(STARTDATE);
//Date after 14 days
DateTime rsDate = stDate.plusDays(14);
```