# Add real days (not days in a year) to java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, calendar

Is there a way to add real days to a `java.util.Calendar` instance?

Example: `Calendar` instance, date set to `01. Dec. 2015`.
Now I want to add `31 days` to the Calendar, so the resulting date should be `01. Jan. 2016`. `DAY_OF_YEAR` doesn't seems suitable because it represents a day in a year, not a real day.

No duplicate: My demand is to add real days to a `Calendar` instance and there is no other post which explains the actual work done by `Calendar.DATE` / `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`.

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding Days to Calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197710/adding-days-to-calendar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe add `Calendar.DATE`?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// add 31 days to the calendar
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 31);
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [add(int field,
       int amount)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method in the [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) Class.

Example:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); //gets a Calendar Instance with the current Date and Time.
System.out.println("Current Date and Time: " + calendar.getTime());
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 31);
System.out.println("Date and Time after adding 31 days: " + calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code to add real days to `calendar`:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 31);
```

Answer (score 1):

java 8 having lots of good features http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

code to have some idea:

```
  import java.time.LocalDate;

    String dt = "2008-01-01";
    int days=31;
    String updateddate=DateIncrementer(dt,days);

    public class DateIncrementer {
      static public String addCustomDay(String date,int noOfDays) {
        return LocalDate.parse(date).plusDays(noOfDays).toString();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`DAY_OF_MONTH` is a synonym for `DATE`, so both should do the same. `DAY_OF_YEAR` is based on the current year, but `DAY_OF_MONTH` is independent from the current month?